# C# EWS Change Folder Permission in other Mailbox

Tags: permissions, outlook, exchangewebservices

when accessing another Mailbox in Exchange 2010 SP2 (I got owner rights to its folders, was checked IN OUTLOOK via Creating/Modifying/Deleting a user permission on Inbox).

Now, if i try the same thing via EWS, i only get "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.". Now I'm actually using the same credentials (Windows Auth) as in outlook, using the following code:

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);            

        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        service.PreAuthenticate = true;

        service.AutodiscoverUrl(<myUser_with_rights>);

        FolderView view = new FolderView(50);

        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);

        SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(FolderSchema.TotalCount, 0);

        view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Shallow;

        FolderId InboxId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, <emailAddressOfOtherMailbox>);
        findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(InboxId, view);

        foreach (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder myFolder in findFolderResults.Folders)
        {                
                myFolder.Load();
                PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, FolderSchema.Permissions);
                Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder fo = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder.Bind(service, myFolder.Id, propSet);

                fo.Permissions.Add(new UserId(<email>,<permission>));
                fo.Update();//<-----Exception occurs
        }
```

It makes no diefference which folder/node is tried to be updated, it always fails. Reading the permissions works instead.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I repro'd your same results. When I gave user B owner permissions to user A's mailbox, user B was able to read folder permissions on folder A's mailbox, but was not able to grant folder perms to user C. I was not able to find a work around so I assume this is by design.